# How can I turn off autorefcount in Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

The system I'm working on has made their own ref counting unit, but it's conflicting with the Delphi one. I've tried to make it compatible with compiler conditions, but I've still come across several bugs that I think might be caused because ARC is still on.

Comment: This continues a theme of your recent questions where you seem to be fighting against the system.  Continue to use AnsiString. Disable ARC. I think you might be better served by trying to go with the flow rather than swimming against the current.

Comment: You're right. I'm also working on alternatives, but it would be nice if I can reuse already existing code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple, you cannot globally turn off Delphi compiler ARC on platforms where it is supported (currently Android and iOS).

However, ARC can be bypassed in code for particular references.

ARC compilers introduce `[weak]` and `[unsafe]` attributes.

`[weak]` can be used for marking weak references that do not participate in reference counting, but you will still need to have at least one strong reference to keep object alive. Weak references are also set to `nil` when object is destroyed.

`[unsafe]` can be used to completely turn of reference counting for specific reference, but it is meant to be used in rare circumstances and it will prohibit you from mixing counted and non-counted references resulting in very limited utilization.

Also, parameters declared as `const` and `var` are not reference counted.

[ARC in Delphi mobile compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers)

Comment: True, you cannot *disable* Delphi's ARC refcounting. But, you can bypass it when needed. Parameters declared as `const` and `var` are not ref-counted. Object variables declared as `[weak]` are no ref-counted (though they are tracked for auto-nil'ing). In cases where `[weak]` is not desired/feisable, you could just resort to `Pointer` type-casts on assignments. Of course, `Free()`/`FreeAndNil()` will no longer work, you would have to call `Destroy()`/`DisposeOf()` directly.  Not a perfect solution, but it might be helpful in some cases.